# Object prints in the console but can't use it to set state - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm making a request to an API for prices of a cryptocurrency for a date range & storing the result in an array.  The goal is to populate a line graph with those prices when the page loads but I can't figure out for the life of my why `pricesArr` prints when I `console.log` it but if I try `this.setState({dataArr: pricesArr})` then I get an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.`

The object in `pricesArr` prints in the console and looks like this:

```
[{USD: 7629.4, EUR: 6503.14}, {USD: 6754.4, EUR: 5432.14} ... ]



class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataArr:[]

     }
   }


  getData(){

    var url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR&ts='

    let pricesArr = []
    for (let i=1; i <= 30; i++) {
      const num = i.toString()
      const date = new Date('2018.06.' + num)
      const unixTimestamp = date / 1000
      const api_url = url + unixTimestamp

      if (i % 5 === 0 || i === 1) {
        axios.get(api_url)
        .then(res => {
            var obj = res.data['BTC']
            pricesArr.push(obj)
        })
      }
    }

    this.setState({dataArr: pricesArr})
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getData()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hi
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is what they call callback hell :D Check this out: https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that your `this` is undefined. try this.

```
  getData = () => {

    var url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR&ts='

    let pricesArr = []
    for (let i=1; i <= 30; i++) {
      const num = i.toString()
      const date = new Date('2018.06.' + num)
      const unixTimestamp = date / 1000
      const api_url = url + unixTimestamp

      if (i % 5 === 0 || i === 1) {
        axios.get(api_url)
        .then(res => {
            var obj = res.data['BTC']
            pricesArr.push(obj)
        })
      }
    }

    this.setState({dataArr: pricesArr})
  }
```

Comment: This works!  Is this because I need to bind it with an arrow function?

Comment: it's the scope, you may either bind the ```this``` or use arrow function that does it for you